# Github desktop for mac cannot login

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I'm new to github and I've just downloaded github desktop for mac (v217), but i cannot login, it always says "could not reach server".
[Image : the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGXqT.png)

I've tried :

- Both my username and email for 'Login';
- Reinstall github desktop;
- Login with Git by trying "git push" to my repo and succeeded;
- And there is no problem with my login on github.com

Thank you for the help ;)

Answer (score 4):

We ran into this same problem. The solution for us was to have the new user check their e-mail and authenticate their account with GitHub.  After we did that we no longer received the vague error message.

Answer (score 3):

I've ran into the same problem. I solved it by:

1. **logging into the web site**
2. then going to https://github.com/settings/applications 
   (Or menu Settings/Authorized Applications)
3. **revoking the access to "Github for MAC"**

4.Then I had to sign in from the Desktop app 2-3 times before it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: If you create by first time the Github Account and try to access to Desktop app (Mac/Windows) the message: "could not reach server" will appears if you haven't clicked in "VERIFY EMAIL" in you inbox.

I just went to email and click on "verify email" link and try again. It worked for me.
[image]